# How do I configure the internet adapters in Enlightenment?

Tags: networking, enlightenment

In Cinnamon, there's this nice dialogue for configuring the network connections, adapters, etc.

[image]

It's a GNOME Shell thing I imagine, but Unity has its own, as do LXDE and XFCE and pretty much every other DE.

Where is the GUI for this purpose in Enlightenment 20? I can't find it anywhere in the Settings. Or must I do it by hand with the command-line?

Comment: IIRC Enlightenment prefers something called connman (and has some plugin GUI for that). I just install WICD instead.

Comment: @muru can haz link   ?

Comment: For WICD? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD